# Problem with PlotLabels

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.4, fixed in 11.0.**

---

Version 10.4 introduced the `PlotLabels` option in `ListPlot` and similar functions. But it seems that it doesn't work when setting the `PlotRange`. For example

```
ListLinePlot[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, PlotRange -> {All, {5.5, 6}}, PlotLabels -> 1]
```

[image]

Could you confirm it as a bug?

I'm using version 10.4 on OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: It doesn't like your `PlotRange`, reporting it.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks!

Comment: Well, you got me to do some work on a Sunday ... :P

Comment: Bug is all over the place with `PlotLabels`, see e.g. `LogPlot[{0, 0.1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLabels -> Automatic]`, `Plot[0, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {.001, All}}, PlotLabels -> All]`. Reported them and TechSupport has filed it internally.

Comment: As a workaround: I note that the problem only arises, when the labels are placed automatically. So `Placed[ lbl, pos ]` will work, if *pos* is different from `Automatic`. In the given example this will work: `ListLinePlot[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, PlotRange -> {All, {5.5, 6}}, 
 PlotLabels -> Placed[1, {0.9, 0.7}]]` where the position specs are relative fractions of the plot's region.

Comment: Is not it supposed to be `PlotLabel` without the `s` at the end?

Comment: @Sumit See rcollyer's comment under Alexei's answer.

Comment: @gwr Unfortunately, the `Placed` workaround is not robust enough, see e.g. `LogPlot[{0, 0.1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLabels -> Placed[{"A", "B"}, Above]]`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks for pointing out. Sometimes one feels like one could "go bonkers" with these things. :)

Comment: 2022 and Plotting is still a pain in the ass in MMA. For me using `PlotLegends` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a matter of an answer, but of a short comment: not `PlotLabels` but `PlotLabel` and everything works.

But just to make this answer more useful, you may check this as follows:

```
 Options[ListLinePlot]

{AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> {}, 
 Background -> None, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, BaseStyle -> {}, 
 ClippingStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ColorOutput -> Automatic, 
 ContentSelectable -> Automatic, CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
 DataRange -> Automatic, DisplayFunction :> $DisplayFunction, 
     Epilog -> {}, Filling -> None, FillingStyle -> Automatic, 
     FormatType :> TraditionalForm, Frame -> False, FrameLabel -> None, 
     FrameStyle -> {}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameTicksStyle -> {}, 
     GridLines -> None, GridLinesStyle -> {}, ImageMargins -> 0., 
     ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
     ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, InterpolationOrder -> None, 
     Joined -> True, LabelStyle -> {}, MaxPlotPoints -> \[Infinity], 
     Mesh -> None, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, MeshShading -> None, 
     MeshStyle -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic, 
     PerformanceGoal :> $PerformanceGoal, PlotLabel -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> None, PlotMarkers -> None, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, 
 PlotRegion -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Automatic, 
 PlotTheme :> $PlotTheme, PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, 
 Prolog -> {}, RotateLabel -> True, TargetUnits -> Automatic, 
 Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> {}}
```

and then find the option you ar5e looking for (and sometimes also the one you never thought of).

Have fun!

Comment: It's fun to watch that Mathematica crashes instantly after I paste everything in the code block into a notebook :)

Comment: @xslittlegrass I have no problem with that. It may be the problem of your notebook. May be restarting would be a good idea.

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/PQrdhn9) is a screenshot, I'm using 10.4 on OS X 10.11.4. What system are you using?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch `PlotLabel` labels the entire plot, i.e. it's the title. `PlotLabels` labels the individual plots.

Comment: @xslittlegrass 10.11.4? I'll forward this to someone who is running that.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, thanks!

Comment: @rcollyer  OK, I have 10.3 on this computer, may be this is the reason that I do not see such an option. However, the general method is to exaluate `Option[functionInQuestion] ` and choose the existing options.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I am using Win7, Mma10.3 on this computer. Tomorrow I will have a look, how is it on 10.4

Comment: @xslittlegrass thus far, we have not been able to reproduce the crash. Can you send `support@wolfram.com` a copy of the crash report along with your `SystemInformation[]`? We'll see if we can hunt it down that way.

Comment: @rcollyer I have reported. I just tried a few times and it seems to have something to do with the automatic switching of my graphics card and the pop out of the floating elements. I'm using an late 2013 model of 15 inch Macbook pro retina, and it has both an intel and nvidia graphics cards. If my computer is using the nvidia graphics card then there is no problem. The problem only occurs when my computer is on intel, and the crash happens when I paste codes and it tries to switch to nvidia.

Comment: @rcollyer Moreover, there is no crash if I move my mouse away before I paste the code, so that the mouse is outside of the posted code. In that sense there is mouse related pop up, and thus no graphics card switch and no crash.

Comment: @xslittlegrass i'll let support try and diagnose then, as I don't have something comparable.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I tried on Mma10.4, Win7. I confirm that your code gives rise to the eoor message and a pink plot also indicating the error. If the PlotRange option is removed, the errors disappear and the code works as expected. This looks like a bug.